# Canadian permanent resident/US citizen re-entering Canada with expired PR card

Tags: canada, international-travel, us-citizens

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162329/canadian-permanent-resident-entering-canada-with-expired-us-passport) reminded me of a parallel situation.

Suppose someone is:

- a permanent Canadian resident
- with an *expired* PR card
- and a valid US passport
- trying to re-enter Canada from the US by air
- after a *short* (say 1-week) trip to the US

Given that US citizens can generally enter Canada without a visa, Can I re-enter Canada (= successfully board the plane, and pass immigration on arrival) with my US passport?

- renewing a PR card takes about 120 days (the website currently says that due to COVID they're not even listing processing times)
- you can [get a permanent resident travel document (PRTD)](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=065) that will work in lieu of a valid PR card, but it's a pain: you have to include your current passport, it can't be applied for from within Canada, long processing times, etc. ...

Comment: Another interesting question would be for someone who holds a visa-exempt but non-US passport who would be required to apply for an ETA which isn't technically available to permanent residents... But I have no idea if the ETA system crosschecks with the PR database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boarding a plane isn't a problem for US citizens for whom an electronic travel authorization is not required.

Since you have an expired permanent resident card, your information should already be registered in the Global Case Management System so the officers could verify the status quite easily, especially with an expired PR card and a valid passport. Once your status is validly established, you have to be allowed entry into Canada.

Sections 11.2 and 11.3 of the [operational guide](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/resources/manuals/enf/enf04-eng.pdf) for port of entry examination procedures have more information:

> The  PRC  is  the  best  evidence  of  permanent  resident  status  in  Canada.
>
> The  following  documents  are  satisfactory  indicators  of  permanent  residence:
>
> - the  original  Record  of  Landing;
> - a certified  true  copy  of  a Record  of  Landing  document  issued  by  IRCC  National Headquarters  (NHQ);
> - a letter  issued  by  IRCC  NHQ  verifying  permanent  residence;
> - a passport  duly  stamped  showing  the  date  on  which permanent  residence  was granted  if  the  person  was  granted  permanent  resident  status  before  1973;
> - a  Confirmation  of  Permanent  Residence  form  [IMM  5292B];  and
> - a permanent  resident  travel  document.
>
> ...
>
> BSOs  at  POEs  have  the  discretion to  authorize  the  entry  of  permanent  residents,  even  in  the absence  of  documentation.  If  documentary  evidence  is  not  available,  the  BSO  at Immigration  Secondary  must establish the  person’s  permanent  resident  status  by questioning the  person  and  checking  the  person’s  status  in  GCMS.
>
> ...

An expired PR card would still count as some sort of documentation, or you may still have the original landing form stapled onto your (perhaps old) passport. However, you may still face some questioning.

Once your PR status is established, you have the right to enter Canada.

> after a short (say 1-week) trip to the US

Also this does not matter much. Review of admissibility and compliance with residency obligations can happen regardless if you have a valid PR card or not. A PR card is "shall-issue" and must be issued to a permanent resident even when the government has already initiated removal proceedings (as long as a final decision has not come into force after the appeal period has lapsed).

An expired PR card may be considered as a ground to suspect possible non-compliance of residency obligations. You have the burden to prove (regardless of the validity of your PR card) that you meet your residency obligations in the five-year period before the date of examination, although you can still enter Canada even if you refuse to answer questions regarding the compliance of your residency obligations (but the officer can continue their investigation and potentially make adverse inferences).

Comment: @xngtng would your answer change at all in the situation where the person is an LPR (lawful permanent resident) with a valid green card instead of a US citizen?

Comment: @Bellarina As U.S. LPRs no longer need an ETA to travel to Canada, the answer is the same.